# jQuery Mask Money and Primefaces inputmask conflict

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

The problem is that just one of the two work a time.

The code that i'm using is the below

```
<h:outputScript  library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head"/>     
<h:outputScript name="jquery.maskMoney.js" library="js" target="head"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".currencyInput").live("focus", function(){
        $(this).maskMoney({thousands:".", allowZero:false, allowNegative:false, decimal:","});
        $(this).bind('paste', function(){return false;});
        $(this).bind('drop', function(){return false;});
    })
</script>
```

And then I just put the styleclass in some inputs...

When I take the second line off prime's masks works and obviosly the maskMoney don't, otherwise, maskMoney works and prime's mask don't.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it was a known issue  [jquery-maskmoney Conflicts with maskedinput.js](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/issues/35)

(maskedinput.js is the jquery plugin that primefaces are using)

So try upgrading to the latest version of maskmoney plugin from here [jquery-maskmoney](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney)

If that wont help, get the latest version of jquery mask plugin that primefaces are using from here [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)